# My first-ever jQuery works, but it's not efficient. Any pointers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written my first completely self-written jQuery today. I just used the jQuery docs and I'm reasonably proud I got it to work, and working fine. It's not a very complex problem I'm solving, just an animated UI element, but it are my first steps, and I want to make sure I'm starting off right.

I think it's a lot of code for what I'm trying to achieve, and I'm looking for pointers or tips on how I could improve my code. I'm not at all averse to scrapping all jQuery here and doing it with pure JS either.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var nav = jQuery(".navigation-menu");
    var button = jQuery(".navigation-title");

    function showNav() {
        nav.show('fast');
        button.removeClass('closed');
        button.addClass('open');
    }

    function hideNav() {
        nav.hide('fast');

        if (button.hasClass('open')) {
            button.removeClass('open');
        }

        button.addClass('closed');
    }

    hideNav();

    button.click(function () {
        if (button.hasClass('closed')) {
            showNav();
        } else if (button.hasClass('open')) {
            hideNav();
        } else if (!button.hasClass('open') || !button.hasClass('closed')) {
            hideNav();
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yeawg/2/

I'm also wondering: am I using event.preventDefault() right?

Answer (score 3):

I found `.toggle()` in the jQuery docs, and it seemed to me I could use that far better. I changed my code into:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var nav = jQuery(".navigation-menu");
    var button = jQuery(".navigation-title");

    nav.toggle();

    button.click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        nav.toggle('fast');
    });
});
```

This looks a lot leaner and better readable.

Answer (score 1):

For one, it can be done [CSS-only](http://jsfiddle.net/yeawg/4/).

JS:

```
None at all. Remove your JS.
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="mobile-navigation">
    <!-- dummy target since CSS has no "prev" -->
    <i id="menu"></i>

    <div class="navigation-menu">
        <a id="menu-open" href="#menu">Menu</a>
        <a id="menu-close" href="#">Menu</a>
    </div>

    <ul id="menu-real" class="navigation-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Cafe</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Toys</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop-in-Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Feestjes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Agenda</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fietsverhuur</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Add this CSS to your existing CSS:

```
/* menu animators */
#menu ~ #menu-real {
    height:0;
    width:0;
    opacity:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#menu:target ~ #menu-real {
    width: 100%;
    height : 100%;
    opacity : 1;
    position:relative;
}

/* Menu button swappers */
#menu ~ * > #menu-open {display:block}
#menu:target ~ * > #menu-open {display:none}

#menu ~ * > #menu-close {display:none}
#menu:target ~ * > #menu-close {display:block}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'm trying to learn more about JavaScript. I'm definitely looking in to your solution however. Seems the better option performance-wise. (Even though it probably won't matter much in this case, at least I don't have to load jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

Some points:

- The `preventDefault` doesn't do anything in a `ready` event handler, as there is no default action that would happen after the event. (If you would use the `preventDefault` method you should declare a parameter in the event handler to catch the event object sent to it.)
- You don't need to check if an element has a class before removing it, if it's not there the `removeClass` method will just change nothing.
- You can chain calls that work with the same jQuery object.
- When checking what to do with the navigation, you can just use an `else` instead of checking every combination.

So:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var nav = jQuery(".navigation-menu");
  var button = jQuery(".navigation-title");

  function showNav() {
    nav.show('fast');
    button.removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
  }

  function hideNav() {
    nav.hide('fast');
    button.removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
  }

  hideNav();

  button.click(function () {
    if (button.hasClass('closed')) {
        showNav();
    } else {
        hideNav();
    }
  });

});
```